# How do I cat a file from a git ls-tree response?

Tags: git

I ran this command on my CLI: `git rev-list --all | xargs -I '{}' git ls-tree --full-tree -r '{}' | grep '.*Foo.*'`  It returned this:

```
100644 blob 33265039940178412e18a8654bef5c31fa9694b5    Assets/Editor/Foo.cs.meta
100644 blob e1f400f00b3efa867436d3b7f040917ca9f5d08c    Assets/Editor/Foo.cs
```

I want to see the contents of Foo.cs, but when I type `git checkout e1f400f00b3efa867436d3b7f040917ca9f5d08c`, it says `fatal: reference is not a tree: e1f400f00b3efa867436d3b7f040917ca9f5d08c`.

How do I see the contents of that file?

Comment: `git cat-file blob <blob>`. That is, don't pass it `Assets/Editor/Foo.cs.meta`, pass it `33265039940178412e18a8654bef5c31fa9694b5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By hash ID:

```
git cat-file -p e1f400f00b3efa867436d3b7f040917ca9f5d08c
```

By name:

```
git cat-file -p <rev>:Assets/Editor/Foo.cs
git show <rev>:Assets/Editor/Foo.cs
```

where `<rev>` is any syntax acceptable to `git rev-parse` that specifies a commit or tree.  For instance if the tag name `v2.1` identifies the commit that contains those files, you could use `git show v2.1:Assets/Editor/Foo.cs`.

(Note: the `-p` flag to `git cat-file` is not really necessary here, but it's important when inspecting a tree object as those are stored as binary data.  You can forcibly specify the expected type of the git object, or just let `-p` figure out how to display it.)

Answer (score 1):

For your example, `git cat-file blob 33265039940178412e18a8654bef5c31fa9694b5` will return the content of `Assets/Editor/Foo.cs.meta`, with no need to do any `git checkout` at all.

Even better, `git cat-file --batch` can be given a stream of IDs on stdin, and will emit content from each of them.

Consider the following as an end-to-end example:

```
git rev-list --all \
  | xargs -d $'\n' -n 1 git ls-tree --full-tree -r \
  | awk '/Foo/ { print $3 }' \
  | git cat-file --batch
```